# mean Value Integral

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

[image]

I can solve this integral in the very general way. But I don't unnderstand  how they have applied the mean value theorem to this integral and solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Integral Mean Value Theorem** says that if $f$ is integrable on $[A,B]$, then 
$$
    \int_A^B f(x)\,dx = (B-A) f(c)
$$
for some $c$ in $(A,B)$.

In your first integral you have $A = \frac{L}{4} - \frac{a}{2}$ and $B = \frac{L}{4} + \frac{a}{2}$.  So $B- A = a$, and since $a$ is “small enough” (according to the note), $c \approx \frac{L}{4}$.  Hence
$$
    \int_{L/4 - a/2}^{L/4 + a/2} f(x)\,dx \approx a f\left(\frac{L}{4}\right)
$$
The other integral is treated similarly.

Comment: I understand your point. But how can i know that, mean value theorem would be best way to solve?

Comment: @SabbirHasan: I'm not sure what you mean by "solve."  You are reading a derivation, and there might be more than way to derive something.